# Apache encoding ascii to utf8

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, apache-config

I've static sub-folders on my server.
All i want is the Apache to forward them the right way.
With normal English sub-folders, I've no problem. example.com/asd -> /srv/fdr/asd.
When the request contains non-ascii letters it convert them like this Büc -> B%C3%BCc, while my folder is named /srv/fdr/Büc (in utf8), the Apache forward it to /srv/fdr/B%C3%BCc.

Any idea on how to change URL path requested encoding ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `RewriteMap` and the *int* (internal functions) to create an unescape map (although it's called "escape"). Since this is a RewriteMap, it needs to be in either the server config (httpd.conf) or virtual host config:

```
RewriteMap unescape int:escape
```

Now you can use **${unescape:}** on your backreference. So if you are matching a URI that has escaped characters, you can wrap your backreference in that in order to unescape. For example:

```
# Need this to avoid rewrite-looping
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/srv/fdr
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /srv/fdr/${unescape:$1} [L,NE]
```

This will take the URI `/B%C3%BCc` and rewrite it to `/srv/fdr/Büc`

Also note that if you put the rewrite rule inside your server or virtualhost config, you need to add a **/** before the **(.+)** in the regex match.